# Knockout afterRender, but just once

Tags: knockout.js

I have a simple observableArray which contains a lot of user-models.
In the markup, there is a template with a foreach loop which loops the users and outputs them in a simple table. I additionally style the table with a custom scrollbar and some other javascript. So now I have to know when the foreach loop is finished and all the models are added to the DOM.

The problem with the afterRender callback is that it gets called every time something is added, but I need kind of a callback which fires only once.

Comment: Why do you need to know when they are rendered into the DOM? If you are applying styles, CSS should just match the rule and apply as the items are added.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a custom binding.  You can either place your custom binding after `foreach` in the list of bindings in your `data-bind` or you could execute your code in a `setTimeout` to allow `foreach` to generate the content before your code is executed.

Here is a sample that shows running code a single time and running code each time that your observableArray updates: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Ampng/

HTML:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: items, updateTableOnce: true">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<hr/>

<table data-bind="foreach: items, updateTableEachTimeItChanges: true">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button data-bind="click: addItem">Add Item</button>
```

JS:

```
var getRandomColor = function() {
   return 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';  
};

ko.bindingHandlers.updateTableOnce = {
    init: function(element) {
        $(element).css("color", getRandomColor());            
    }    
};

//this binding currently takes advantage of the fact that all bindings in a data-bind will be triggered together, so it can use the "foreach" dependencies
ko.bindingHandlers.updateTableEachTimeItChanges = {
    update: function(element) {    
        $(element).css("color", getRandomColor());  
    }    
};


var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
        { id: 1, name: "one" },
        { id: 1, name: "one" },
        { id: 1, name: "one" }
    ]),
    addItem: function() {
        this.items.push({ id: 0, name: "new" });   
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Is there any way of getting this working within a `template: {foreach: ...}` call?

Comment: @JulesCopeland you could go with something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Ampng/37/ where the binding grabs a dependency on the array.

Comment: This is do not work with knockout 3.4.2 as @j-a mention.

Answer (score 10):

I came up with an elegent cheat. Immediately after your template / foreach block, add this code:

```
<!--ko foreach: { data: ['1'], afterRender: YourAfterRenderFunction } -->
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and saved me a lot of hassle, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

A quick and simple way is to, in your afterRender handler, compare the current item with the last item in your list. If it matches, then this is the last time afterRender is run.

Comment: This is clever. I didn't think of this!

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thanks for the suggestion!  This cuts down on my scroll function being called once for each message(possibly a thousand times) to once.  Keep it simple stupid, perfect!

Answer (score 3):

Jaffa's answer has contains an error so I decided to create a new answer instead of commenting. It is not possible to use with and template at the same time.
So just move your model to template's `data` tag

**Html**

```
<div data-bind="template: {data: myModel, afterRender: onAfterRenderFunc }" >
   <div data-bind="foreach: observableArrayItems">
       ...
   </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myModel = {      
  observableArrayItems : ko.observableArray(),

  onAfterRenderFunc: function(){
    console.log('onAfterRenderFunc')
  }

}
ko.applyBinding(myModel);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if the accepted answer will work in knockout-3.x (as data-bindings no longer are run in the order you declare them).

Here is another option, it will only fire exactly once.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.mybinding {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var foreach = allBindings().foreach,
                subscription = foreach.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                // do something here 
                subscription.dispose(); // dispose it if you want this to happen exactly once and never again.
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: Just to point out, if foreach is declared using "as" syntax `foreach: { data: array, as: 'item' }`, then subscribe function is on the prototype of data property. So, one should use `allBindings.get("foreach").data.subscribe`.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head you could either:

- Instead of hooking into the afterRender event, simply call your function after you have push/popped an item on the array.
- Or possibly wrap the observableArray in an observable which in itself has the child items underneath with its own afterRender event.  The foreach loop would need to refer to the parent observable like so:

Example:

```
 <div>
     <div data-bind="with: parentItem(), template: { afterRender: myRenderFunc }" >
      <div data-bind="foreach: observableArrayItems">
          ...
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Not tested this so just guessing...

Comment: Getting an error: Message: `Multiple bindings (with and template) are trying to control descendant bindings of the same element. You cannot use these bindings together on the same element.`

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out when the foreach template has completed rendering, you can make a "dummy" binding and pass the current rendered item index to your handler and check if its match the array length.

**HTML:**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: list">
   <li>
   \\ <!-- Your foreach template here -->
   <div data-bind="if: $root.listLoaded($index())"></div> 
   </li>
</ul>
```

**ViewModel - Handler:**

```
this.listLoaded = function(index){
    if(index === list().length - 1)
       console.log("this is the last item");
}
```

Hold extra flag if you intend to add more items to the list.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a debouncer?

```
var afterRender = _.debounce(function(){    

    // code that should only fire 50ms after all the calls to it have stopped

}, 50, { leading: false, trailing: true})
```